# Por que não consigo imprimir conteúdo em Lista Encadeada

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Boa noite, estou com um problema em um trabalho da faculdade. Preciso criar uma lista encadeada que receba registros de alunos. Criei uma função para cadastro, contudo, não consigo imprimir, externamente, o conteúdo da mesma utilizando o ponteiro do primeiro. Gostaria de saber o porquê disso estar acontecendo.

Por exemplo, dentro do escopo da função ele consegue imprimir com `(*((*a).alunoPosterior)).nome)`, porém quando vou pra fora não consigo fazê lo utilizando `(*(a.alunoPosterior)).nome`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define length 100

typedef struct aluno {
    int matricula;
    int telefone;

    double n1;
    double n2;
    double n3;
    double media;

    char nome[length];
    char email[length];

    struct aluno *alunoAnterior;
    struct aluno *alunoPosterior;
} Aluno;

void criarAluno(Aluno *a);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    Aluno a;

    gets(a.nome);
    criarAluno(&a);

    printf("NOME A = %s\nNOME B = %s", a.nome,  (*(a.alunoPosterior)).nome);

    return 0;
}

/**
    A função cria um struct de Aluno. Em seguida, vincula o struct recém-criado ao ponteiro (*a)
    do mesmo tipo que veio através do parâmetro.
*/
void criarAluno(Aluno *a) {
    Aluno b;

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Insira o nome do aluno: ");
    gets(b.nome);

  /*  printf("\nInsira o número de matrícula do aluno: ");
    scanf("%d", &b.matricula);

    printf("\nInsira o número de telefone do aluno: ");
    scanf("%d", &b.telefone);

    printf("\nInsira a Nota 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &b.n1);

    printf("\nInsira a Nota 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &b.n2);

    printf("\nInsira a Nota 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &b.n3);

    b.media = (b.n1 + b.n2 + b.n3)/3;*/

    (*a).alunoPosterior = &b;

    printf("%s\n\n", (*((*a).alunoPosterior)).nome);
    b.alunoAnterior = a;
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do que posso fazer?

Comment: A sua pergunta não esta muito clara estou tendo dificuldade em entender o que vc quer, vc poderia editar ela e ser mais objetivo.

Comment: Pergunta Editada!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui responder quando substituí a declaração `Aluno b` por :

```
Aluno *b = (Aluno*) malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
```

Comment: Não deves fazer cast a malloc.

Comment: Por que não devo?

Comment: Redundância.Acabas por te repetir o que é mau, por diminuir a legibilidade ou nos piores casos por esconder um erro. Podes ler mais aqui  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc , aviso é em inglês.

Comment: HDeiro não é assim que se aloca memoria para o seu objeto. Faça da seguinte maneira  `aluno = (struct Aluno *) (malloc(sizeof(struct Aluno) * 1));`. O `*` aponta para o conteúdo da memoria é usado para acessar dados de um ponteiro.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância mas... Pra quê multiplicar o sizeof por 1?

Comment: é apenas uma convenção para dizer que vai ter o tamanho de 1, não é necessário, é apenas representativo.